# loopback interceptor for findOne

Tags: loopbackjs

I have two models and both of them have Users. Let's call them:

Users_A
Users_B

I have to find a user in Users_A, but if it doesn't exist in Users_A then I have to search on Users_B.

If the user exists on User_B then I want to return it when I call Users_A.findOne()

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create remote method to achieve this task and define async waterfall method to run code through several models.

for example:
in remote method execution:

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback){
      //find results on USERS_A
    },
    function(data,callback){
      //find results on USERS_B
    }],
    function(err){
    if(err) console.log(err);

    //return final result from either USERS_A or USERS_B
    }
);
```

hope this method will helpful.

cheers.

Comment: Thank you Chamal for your answer. I don't know if that would have worked, but I posted the answer that I managed myself to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in this way:

```
Users_A.afterRemote('findOne' function(ctx, instance, next) {
    if (ctx.result) {
        return next();
    } else {
        Users_A.app.models.Users_B.findOne(ctx.req.query.filter, 
        (error, data) => {
            if (data) {
                //some logic here
                return next();
            } else {
                //instance the error
                return next(error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That worked for me, hope it helps